# How can I override a Bootstrap page-title under page-title for a specific page in css

Tags: html, css

I have a abc.css which contains the configurations for multiple pages.
For a specific page, I need to override  h4 heading alone to a new configuration rather than the existing one inside this css file. How can I do that?

Comment: So you have a .CSS file for multiple pages but for the new page you need a different .CSS file to be used? How about not including the abc.css?

Comment: This is for handling only h4 section of that page. h3 is already handled within abc.css. For some reason, h4 override, similar to h3 is not happening.

Comment: if you kindly include the html we can show you the selector. Oh, and please add something unique, a class for example, in the html for that header or the body.

Comment: Thanks.. I cant put office code in public network, sorry..

Answer (score 1):

the best approach will be creating separate .css file for each .html page.
but if you want to use single css then use different Id to the element for which you want to give custom css

ex-

```
button{
color:yello;
}
#examplebtn{
color:red;
}
```

here all buttons in the web page will have yellow color but only the button with `ID='examplebtn'` will have yello color

also you can try - !important`enter code here`  to css which you want to 
override

ex-

```
p{
text-align :center !important
}
```

this will override all the css applied on p for text-align are different

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.. I had traced down the path to that specific element and changed the css for that element.